# Why does calling Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors on a date object return an empty array?

Tags: javascript, object, types, descriptor

I'm trying to understand how JavaScript objects work fully. I know that when you call `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors` on an object, you get an object containing the descriptors. For example, if you defined your own object, and got the descriptors, you would get something like this:

```js
let foo = {
  bar: 2
}

Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(foo);
// Output: 
// {
//   bar: {
//     value: 2,
//     writable: true,
//     enumerable: true,
//     configurable: true,
//   }
// }
```

Likewise, if you get the descriptors on a built-in object, e.g. like an `Error`, you can see the descriptors of the error object.

```js
let foo = new Error();

Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(foo);
// Output: 
// {
//   bar: {
//     value: 'Error\n    at <anonymous>:1:11',
//     writable: true,
//     enumerable: false,
//     configurable: true,
//   }
// }
```

I understand that the property was created when the Error constructor was called. Everything that I've just stated makes sense to me. However, when I try to get the descriptors of a date object, nothing is returned.

```js
let foo = new Date();

Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(foo);
// Output: 
// {}
```

I can get the value of the date as a string just by accessing it, but why is there not a descriptor for the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date objects are not said to contain any own-properties. Per [the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-properties-of-date-instances):

> ### 21.4.5 Properties of Date Instances
>
> Date instances are ordinary objects that inherit properties from the Date prototype object. Date instances also have a [[DateValue]] internal slot. The [[DateValue]] internal slot is the time value represented by this Date.

And that's it.

All the information contained for a given Date is within that `[[DateValue]]` internal slot, which is not exposed directly via JavaScript - it's accessed and manipulated only through the methods on `Date.prototype`, the object that date instances inherit from.

> I can get the value of the date as a string just by accessing it

This works because you'd be calling the `toString` method which exists *on the prototype*. For example:

```js
const proto = {
  toString() {
    return 'foo';
  }
};
const instance = Object.create(proto);
console.log(instance.toString());
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(instance));
```

The object can have `toString` called on it without having any properties directly on the instance.